# ElectronJs Print Silently PDF

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, pdf, electron

I have a simple electronJS application which interacts with my laravel backend server. The backend server produces a PDF to a certain size such as 86mm x 54mm and streams the PDF to my electronJS application for it to print silently to the default printer. Currently in my Electron application I get the popup to save the streamed PDF to the machine rather than it print silently.

My electronJs code handling the print method.

```
const printWindow = new BrowserWindow({ show: false });
printWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8000/pass');
printWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
   printWindow.print({ silent: true, deviceName: '' });
});
```

My laravel code for returning the PDF after hitting a route.

```
Route::get('/pdf', function () {
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.layout');
    $pdf->setPaper([0, 0, 175.748, 243.78], 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('pdf.pdf');
});
```

I expected the pdf to print to the default printer however this produces a popup to download the PDF file?

Comment: save issue here with electron 6.0.12. did you ever find a solution around it?

Comment: @koo9 no unfortunately, I believe you are meant to save the streamed file to a temporary location then print silently however I ended up creating an alternative electron window for pass template as all I am doing is printing a simple label.

Comment: I end up using pdf-to-printer. which will take the downloaded file and print to the label printer. under mean for win32 it use SumatraPDF.exe for printing.

Comment: Nice, could you link a repo so I check out a library?

Comment: @Dev.Wol I think the link is this one: https://github.com/artiebits/pdf-to-printer